# vim cgn "E35: No previous regular expression"

Tags: macos, vim

I am pretty new to vim (on macOS highsierra and vim installed via homebrew) and I was trying to mark and replace a text object with the cgn command sequence. This was working a few times, but all off a sudden on `cgn`, I keep getting this error message

> E35: No previous regular expression

As far as I understand this error might occur when the user has no rights to write to `~/.viminfo`. So I explicitly set

```
sudo chmod 666 .viminfo
```

But I still keep getting this error message.

Comment: you have to search something first use `/my_search`

Comment: Thanks, great! Make this answer please, so I can give you your points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `:h gn`. There it says: Search forward for the last used search pattern.

So you have to have a last used search pattern. The search in vim is the slash `/` command. Since the search takes a regular expression the error says regular expression, not search term.

So what is the difference to the normal `n` movement? Well `gn` selects the searched term. If you use a command, in your case `c`hange with `gn` it will only change the searched term, while `cn` will change everything up to the searched term.

Comment: Since `cgn` often used to replace a word (e.g. a variable) it is also good to mention `wildcard` command which selects the word under the cursor. By default `*` will jump to the next occurrence so if you do not like this, place the following to your `.vimrc` file: `nnoremap <silent>* :let @/ = printf("\\<\\C%s\\>", expand("<cword>"))<CR>:set hlsearch<CR>`.

Comment: @damage220 Ah i see, more of a `:s//g` guy myself, but this is useful to know thanks.

Answer (score 2):

E35: No previous regular expression

```
sudo chown $(id -nu):$(id -ng) ~/.viminfo
```

Run this command and Delete swp file, It's worked in my case

```
vim -r config.py
```